# Latex in Arxiv abstract

Tags: arxiv

I am submitting an article in Arxiv.

I need to write abstract for that.

I have written in latex but when I copy the same in abstract there is a problem with citation. I have uploaded  .bbl file in Arxiv. When I compile, its is not taking \cite{some name} where “some name” is some label in .bbl file.

I have written `\<https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605694>` but it is not compiling correctly.

Can some one suggest how to cite a webpage correctly in Arxiv abstract?

Comment: By arXiv abstract do you mean the abstract which appears on the webpage https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605694?  If so the bare URL should be sufficient (without any markup) though [for an arxiv paper the "arXiv:YYMM.NNNN(N)" reference is apparently preferred](https://arxiv.org/help/prep#abstracts).

Comment: @DaiBowen That is correct.. Thanks

Comment: @DaiBowen writing arXiv:arch-ive/0511696 is not working. It is only showing as arXiv:arch-ive/0511696

Comment: Does it become clickable?  I'd check with the arXiv support, it may only become clickable after submission or something else may be needed.  Either way this is an arXiv question rather than a TeX one so [contact their help](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) if the online advice is insufficient/does not work.

Comment: @DaiBowen In that case I will wait till it gets accepted.. It is mentioned that it will show up in Arxiv on 2nd July..

Comment: Do take note that the abstract cannot be changed (after this version has been pushed) without issuing a new version, but yes, if you put `arXiv:math/0605694` then at least for the time being everything should be clear.

Comment: @DaiBowen Oh.. I will change it then :)

Answer (score 2):

arXiv-ids entered into the metadata abstract are automatically linked into a clickable link at the time of announcement. Currently the submission system does not convert links into clickable entities in order to keep you within the submission system and prevent mistakenly leaving a submission.

You do not need (or want) to enter the full URI for a link, as this will get converted into "this HTTPs URL" at announcement rather than `arXiv:YYMM.NNNNN` (or for the older formats, `arXiv:archive/YYMMNNN`). The `arXiv:` prefix is not required, but is considered the standard form of the canonical identifiers.